# Difficulties in understanding algebraic data type

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming, algebraic-data-types

I am not quite sure what this ZInt is actually describing.

```
data Nat = Zero | S Nat
data ZInt = Z Nat Nat deriving Show

addZ :: ZInt -> ZInt -> ZInt
addZ (Z a b) (Z c d) = Z (add a c) (add b d)

with
add ::  Nat -> Nat -> Nat
add a Zero  = a
add a (S b) = S (add a b)

mult :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
mult _ Zero  = Zero
mult a (S b) = add a (mult a b)
```

At first glance i thought maybe it's a presentation of complex numbers, adding imaginary and real  components (in function addZ) without displaying form of

```
a+b*i
```

But what is happening in this functions?

```
 subZ :: ZInt -> ZInt -> ZInt 
 subZ (Z a b) (Z c d) = Z (add a d) (add b c)

multZ :: ZInt -> ZInt -> ZInt
multZ (Z a b) (Z c d) = Z (add (mult a d) (mult c b)) (add (mult a c) (mult b d))
```

So I do understand  data Nat = Zero | S Nat and also the add and mult functions, but not addZ, subZ and multZ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `ZInt` is representing each integer as an *ordered* pair of natural numbers. @freestyle covers how this representation works well; I will just expand on how the arithmetic operators take advantage of this encoding.

`addZ`, `subZ` and `multZ` are simply manipulating the pair of natural numbers that represent each integer.

```
addZ (Z a b) (Z c d) = Z (add a c) (add b d)
(a - b) + (c - d) == a - b + c - d
                  == a + c - b - d
                  == (a + c) - (b + d)

subZ (Z a b) (Z c d) = Z (add a d) (add b c)
(a - b) - (c - d) == a - b - c + d
                  == a + d - b - c
                  == (a + d) - (b + c)

multZ (Z a b) (Z c d) = Z (add (mult a d) (mult c b)) (add (mult a c) (mult b d))
(a - b) * (c - d) == ac - ad - bc + bd
                  == ac + bd - ad - bc
                  == (ac + bd) - (ad + bc)
```

Note that the given definition of `multZ` can get the sign wrong; it should be

```
multZ (Z a b) (Z c d) = Z (add (mult a c) (mult b d)) (add (mult a d) (mult b c))
```

(For clarity, it should also use `mult b c` instead of `mult c b`, even though multiplication of natural numbers is commutative.)

Answer (score 8):

It's just integer numbers. `Nat` represents a natural number. `ZInt` represents an integer number. In `Z a b` if `a >= b` then integer is a - b else -(b - a).

For example:

```
ZInt representation | Traditional representation
Z Zero Zero         | 0
Z (S Zero) Zero     | 1
Z Zero (S Zero)     | -1
Z (S Zero) (S Zero) | 0
...
```

As we can see, to `negate` an integer you just swap the `Nat` values in its representation:

```
negate :: ZInt -> ZInt
negate (Z n m) = Z m n
```

And we can define `subZ` like this:

```
a `subZ` b = a `addZ` negate b
```

This representation is not canonical, `Z (S Zero) (S Zero)` is the same integer as `Z Zero Zero`. So, we can define canonical form like this:

```
canonical :: ZInt -> ZInt
canonical (Z (S n) (S m)) = canonical (Z n m)
canonical x               = x
```

What reason is to define integer numbers by this way?

First of all, it mathematically clear. If someone defined the set of natural number named `N` the we can easy define the set of integers named `Z` as `Z = N * N` where (*) is product of two sets.

In Haskell, I can see only one reason for that. By this way we can define integer numbers on type level.

Comment: `-(b-a)` is the same as `(a-b)`.

Comment: @bereal No, because `a` and `b` are natural numbers and if `a < b` then result of `a - b` isn't defined.

Comment: "pair of Nuts". Well, that's one possible interpretation.

Comment: @n.m. "pair of Nuts" is technical point of view. Logically, it's integer number (this conclusion was derived from function definitions)

Comment: `canonical` can be simplified by listing the both-non-zero case first. The other two cases then reduce to `canonical x = x`.